# Get input Value when user end typing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know only the keyup blur and on input methods but they get the value when user is typing. Is there any method to get the value when user end typing

```
$("#quick-search-input").on("input", function(){
    var searchid = $(this).val().trim();
});
```

Comment: Yeah but user must blur I want to get input at the end of type not on blur.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout` to check if the user finishes typing. 
You start a timer and clear it every time the user starts typing, if the user stops the method in the timeout will be invoked.

```
var timer;
$("#quick-search-input").on("keyup", function(){
    var searchid = $(this).val().trim();

    clearInterval(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('User finished typing !!');
    }, 200);
});
```

Comment: Tried it before but didn't clear the timer thanks why using keyup and not input?

Comment: @DatJavascript Glad to have helped. You could use `input` event as well.

Comment: nice solution , but only problem if the user is a crappy typist and takes longer than 200ms to type the next character.

Comment: @gavgrif  You could maybe increase the timeout .. Maybe 500ms. But if the user is still slow then you have to fallback for the `blur` event

Comment: thats why i prefer to not rely on a timeout function and simply update the value on each key stroke of that input - does not matter when they type of how long between keystrokes, or if they come back to the input at a later time, the value of serachid (or whatever) will be the last typed value.

Answer (score 0):

use keyup and invoke the function and when they finish typing it will be the last value listed. Means you don't have to worry about trying to listen for when they have stopped typing. When the input loses focus, the last value will still be valid and it will be the same as if they had stopped typing.

```
$("#quick-search-input").on("keyup", function(){
    var searchid = $(this).val().trim();
});
```